# Integrating tkinter event loop in ipython notebook

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook, ipython, event-loop

With a simple tkinter gui like this:

```
import tkinter as tk       

class Application(tk.Frame):              
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)   
        self.grid()                       
        self.createWidgets()

    def printHello(self):
        print("Hello")

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit',
            command=self.quit)            
        self.quitButton.grid(row=1,column=0)    
        self.printButton = tk.Button(self, text='Print',command=lambda: self.printHello())         
        self.printButton.grid(row=1,column=1) 
app = Application()                        
app.master.title('Sample application')     
app.mainloop()
```

I am trying to follow this documentation to connect the event loop with the ipython notebook's kernel: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/eventloops.html

But I can't quite seem to grasp how it works especially: `@register_integration('tk')`

How can I exactly connect the event loops? And if I do, what can I do with a connected event loop?

Comment: from IPython.lib.inputhook import register

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is something like this:

```py
from ipykernel.eventloops import register_integration

@register_integration("tk")
def loop_tk(kernel):
    import tkinter as tk

    """Start a kernel with the Tk event loop."""
    class Application(tk.Frame):              
        def __init__(self, master=None):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)   
            self.grid()                       
            self.createWidgets()

        def printHello(self):
            print("Hello")

        def createWidgets(self):
            self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit',
                command=self.quit)            
            self.quitButton.grid(row=1,column=0)    
            self.printButton = tk.Button(self, text='Print',command=lambda: self.printHello())         
            self.printButton.grid(row=1,column=1)


    kernel.window = tk.Tk()
    kernel.app = Application(kernel.window)
    kernel.window.title('Sample application')

    kernel.window.mainloop()

%gui tk
```

First, you need to import the function (which I do not think is documented anywhere).

Second, you need to register the integration and define the `loop_tk` function. You must run a `Tk` instance instead of a `Frame`, because the `Frame` does not have a `mainloop` function.

Finally, use the magic `gui tk` to indicate you're creating a Tk event loop.